# RavenDB: Phonetic and Simpleanalyzer in one query

Tags: ravendb

I want to search for names by a custom phonetic analyzer and the build-in simpleanalyzer.
The result should be ordered that the result of the simpleanalyzer comes first and then the result of the phonetic analyzer.
The only way I found is to make two queries and sort the results on the RavenDB-client.

Is there another possibility to query and sort on serverside with a kind of combined analyzer?